# C# How to assign a string to a double

Tags: c#, string, double

I need help figuring out how to assign a string to a double.

```
double value = "myString";
```

I have `double value = double.Parse("myString");`  but this throws a `FormatException`.

I have trying to concatenate like this:

```
string stringValue += doubleValue.toString() + intValue.ToString;
return stringValue;
```

Comment: What exactly is the string you're passing to `double.parse()`?

Comment: And what do you expect `"myString"` to convert to?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Your examples do not really show what you are trying to do.  If you provide some more details as to your goals, maybe we can offer a better suggestion

Comment: What does the concatenation have to do with parsing doubles? Are you then getting a double based on the result?

Comment: You simply can't get a numerical value from a word. What's elephants add 29? A typo maybe, but you're also trying to add a string to a method group.

Answer (score 3):

> I have double value = double.Parse("myString"); but this throws a string.Format error.

Yes, that's the behaviour you want in this case. "myString" doesn't have a numerical value, so the correct numerical value to give it, is to throw a formatting error.

`double.Parse("1.2")` would work or not depending on whether the culture in use was one where 1.2 was represented as "1.2" or as "1,2". `double.Parse("1.2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`  will always return 1.2, because it's specific about which culture to use.

`double.TryParse`  is useful where it's likely for someone to pass an inappropriate string (like "myString") because it returns a boolean representing success or failure, rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: @L.B I suppose we could design a custom CultureInfo in which "myString" was a way of representing 54.23, and then it would no longer throw!

Answer (score 1):

[Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx#Y0) it, assuming myString is a valid double string representation (eg "3.49", "1394.293", "-1.30E3")

```
double value = double.Parse(myString)
```

Most (All?) of the normal numerical types have parse methods. Use TryParse if you're unsure if it's valid (Trying to parse "abc" as a number will throw an exception)

@L.B For custom parsing you can define a NumberFormatInfo like this:

```
    var a = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo()
    a.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
    a.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
    double d = Double.Parse("1.000.000,5", a);
```

Comment: `1.000.000,5` is valid or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can use TryParse

```
string x = "1234";
double y;
if(double.TryParse(x, out y))
{
    Console.WriteLine("success y = " + y.ToString());
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(x + " could not be converted to a double");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a string to a double. It's impossible. A double is a numerical type. A string is not.

If you parse a string that is a double it is possible.

```
var doubleThing = Double.Parse("9.99");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double.Parse(string);
```

Can and will through an exception if the format is incorrect. What are you trying to parse?

```
double.TryParse("1.05", out value);
```

Will return true or false if the parse succeeds or fails.